# DateTime TimeZone in php

Tags: php, timezone

I am running two different scripts on different servers , I just need to get exact DateTime in both servers. so I need to set time zone for NewYork city regardless changing the php.ini ( I do not need to set using php.ini )

```
 php script :
 public static function formatMysql($str = 'now')
    {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($str));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');//Your global default timeZone.

function convertTimeZone($oTime, $oTimeZone, $nTimeZone) 
{
//Parameter string $oTime is original time to be converted from in format F-d-Y h:i:s
//Parameter string $oTimeZone is timezone to be conveted from- Timezone of $oTimeZone
//Parameter string $nTimeZone is timezone to be conveted to

date_default_timezone_set($oTimeZone);  //Change default timezone to old timezone within this function only.

$originalTime = new DateTime($oTime);

$originalTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($nTimeZone)); //Convert to desired TimeZone.

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles') ; //Reset default TimeZone according to your global settings.

return $originalTime->format('F-d-Y h:i:s A'); //Return converted TimeZone.
} 

$LATime = convertTimeZone("2011-01-07 19:55:00","America/Chicago", "America/Los_Angeles");

echo $LATime;
```

Comment: I am using amazon queuing system (SQS) in my script to write messages there.. when I used the above code , the messages Could not be delivered to SQS until I removed the code above